# Update nested array in Elasticsearch

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm tryng to set-up a project for upsert data in elastisearch I have the following document:

```
{
"PropertyOne": "propertyone",
  "PropertyTwo": "propertytwo",
  "MyArray": [
      {
        "FirstObjArrayPropertyOne": "ArrayPropertyOne",
        "FirstObjArrayPropertyTwo": "ArrayPropertyTwo",
      },
      {
        "SecondObjArrayPropertyOne": "ArrayPropertyOne",
        "SecondObjArrayPropertyTwo": "ArrayPropertyTwo",
      }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to replace the value of "MyArray" and it will looks like:

```
{
 "PropertyOne": "propertyone",
  "PropertyTwo": "propertytwo",
  "MyArray": [
      {
        "NewObjectOne": "ArrayPropertyOne",
        "NewObjectOne": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
      },
      {
        "NewObjectTwo": "ArrayPropertyOne",
        "NewObjectTwo": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
      },
      {
        "NewObjectThree": "ArrayPropertyOne",
        "NewObjectThree": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
      }
    ]
}
```

I use Nest Api for .NET and I create a `painless` script as follow

```
ctx._source.MyArray = [
  {
    "NewObjectOne": "ArrayPropertyOne",
    "NewObjectOne": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
  },
  {
    "NewObjectTwo": "ArrayPropertyOne",
    "NewObjectTwo": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
  },
  {
    "NewObjectThree": "ArrayPropertyOne",
    "NewObjectThree": "ArrayPropertyTwo"
  }
]
```

And the error is

```
{Type: script_exception Reason: "compile error" CausedBy: "Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "invalid sequence of tokens near ['{']." CausedBy: "Type: no_viable_alt_exception Reason: """"}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advice

Comment: What is your mapping look like ? And could you share the code while you are trying to index the document ?

Comment: Check out the example Painless script in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42800992/1831 (last example). This is appending to an existing array, but with a small change to the script you can overwrite the array instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - Add element inside nested List<T> using NEST 5.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787404/elasticsearch-add-element-inside-nested-listt-using-nest-5-x)